# В чем ошибка моего кода?

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
start = (a-c=d-1)//d*d+c
for i in range(start,b+1, d):
    print(i)
```

Comment: `(a-c=d-1)` место знака `=` должно стоять что другое

Comment: Спасибо! В век бы не нашел! Отвечайте и я сделаю Ваш ответ лучшим!

Comment: Вопрос вызван **проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой**. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) проблемы до публикации вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
start = (a - c == d - 1) // d ** 2 + c
for i in range(start, b + 1, d):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: @ПавелПоцелуйко a?